# Parity Lookup Table generation

Tags: c, bit, parity

I was reading bit twiddling hacks for computing parity from this link: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityMultiply)

For computing parity, there is a lookup method, which generates parity table for integers from 0 to 255 with 5 codes of line.

```
#define P2(n) n, n ^ 1, n ^ 1, n 
#define P4(n) P2(n), P2(n ^ 1), P2(n ^ 1), P2(n) 
#define P6(n) P4(n), P4(n ^ 1), P4(n ^ 1), P4(n) 
#define LOOK_UP P6(0), P6(1), P6(1), P6(0)

unsigned int table[256] = { LOOK_UP };
```

I checked the values P2(n) and P4(n) which calculates the parity for [0..15]. But I didn't understand the intuition behind these lines of code. How do these lines calculate the parity of [0..255]? I want to know the intuition and theory behind this recursive approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As all of this code holds up when compiling with C, I suggest retagging as C. In modern C++, one could use `constexpr` to make this table

Answer (score 1):

For P2, parity of bit set to 1 is trivial:

```
0b00 -> 0
0b01 -> 1
0b10 -> 1
0b11 -> 0
```

Prepend `00` doesn't change parity,
but prepend next `01` change parity:

```
0b0100 -> 1 // 0 ^ 1
0b0101 -> 0 // 1 ^ 1
0b0110 -> 0 // 1 ^ 1
0b0111 -> 1 // 0 ^ 1
```

Parity of `0b10..` is the same as `0b01..` and will change again with `0b11..`

`n ^ 1` allow the switch:

```
n | n ^ 1
--|--------
0 | 1
1 | 0
```

alternatively `!n` might have been chosen or other formula with same table

Hope you see the pattern now.

Comment: 0x0100, is this binary or hexadecimal? If this is binary the second code doesn't hold block of parity doesn't hold.

Comment: I mean binary, prefix and typo fixed.